# Using Virtual Keyboard with jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, keyboard, virtual

After struggeling for many days and searching the various fora I'll give it a go here.

I can't get the jQuery UI autocomplete widget working with the Mottie Virtual Keyboard (https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard).
jQuery Autocomplete with ajax loaded values works fine as long as you're using the physical keyboard. 
If I enter 2 characters through the virtual keyboard, I see these characters but no autocomplete list. If I enter the third character on the physical keyboard it shows the first list. So the physical entered data correctly appends to the virtual entered data.
Tried to leave out the Ajax part and use some simple words as test, same behaviour.
Checked IE, Firefox, Chrome: all the same.
Also selecting a value from the autocomplete list through the mouse doesn't work.

Anyone solved this and created a working example?

Here's my test code:

```
<... load jQuery, virtual keyboard, CSS etc...>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            function log(message) {
                $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
                $("#log").scrollTop(0);
            }
            $('#sometext').keyboard({
                usePreview: false,
                position: {at: 'right bottom', of: '#log'}
            }).autocomplete({
                source: ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Musketiers'],
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item) {
                        log("Selected: " + ui.item.label);
                    }
                }
            }).addAutocomplete();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="sometext">Some label: </label>
    <input id="sometext" />
</div>
<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top: 2em; font-family: Arial;">
    <div id="log" style="height: 50px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>
```

Update:
It looks like the Mottie Virtual keyboard can't find the jQuery autocomplete. In the source (line 88 onwards) it says:

```
// set up after keyboard is visible
base.autocomplete_setup = function() {
    // look for autocomplete
    base.$autocomplete = base.$el.data('autocomplete');
    base.hasAutocomplete = (typeof(base.$autocomplete) === 'undefined') ? false : (base.$autocomplete.options.disabled) ? false : true;
```

The 'base.hasAutocomplete' turns out to be false

Answer (score 3):

This problem solved in the newer version of jquery.keyboard.extension-autocomplete.js.

according to [this](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/issues/177)  the autocomplete code for checking the JQuery-UI version had problems with JQuery-UI version 1.10
and also below changes are made in jquery.keyboard.extension-autocomplete.js:

```
base.$autocomplete = base.$el.data('autocomplete'); //removed
base.$autocomplete = base.$el.data('autocomplete') || base.$el.data('uiAutocomplete'); //added
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.